# What's the meaning of the expression "wiggle room" in the phrase bellow?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here, too, there is still a fair amount of wiggle room for the label. For example, the record label may be paying personnel $10 per hour but charge a retail price of $40 per hour when charging the cost of the personnel to the album as a direct cost.

Comment: It's in the [dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wiggle%20room): LEEWAY, LATITUDE // a contract with *wiggle room* for further negotiations."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The record label company is making a profit of $30 per employee per hour, because it pays $10 but receives $40. Profit can be reinvested into a company, allowing it to change its course of business, pay more to its employees, charge a lower price to consumers for each recording album, etc. This is wiggle room – opportunity to do things by differently, or to make mistakes. (As for the phrase “wiggle room” itself, imagine you’re stuck in a coffin underground but you have a little room to wiggle your fingers, toes, shoulders!)

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for the explanation.